# How to focus second Cell when add a new row in dojo.gridX

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid, dojo.gridx, gridx

I am using `dojo.gridx` to display my values. Sometimes user can create a new row. So that I have added a new button when click newRow button, will call onclick method.

In that method has create new row codes. My codes are below.

addRow:

```
function() {
    var that = this;
    var gridIdLocal = dijit.byId('GridId');

    that.lastIndex+=1;  ( last index count I get externally)    
    var newRow = {
        Id : '',
        ClassDES:'',
        createdDate: that.getTodayDate(),
        activatedDate:that.getTodayDate(),
        deactivedDate:'',
        activeStatus:'Y',
        id : lastIndex
    };
    gridIdLocal.store.newItem(newRow);
    gridIdLocal.store.save();            
},
```

By this code I am able to create a new row but I want to focus my mouse cursor point to newly added row's second column(ClassDES).
How can I achieve this functionality in `dojo.gridx`?

Comment: Please someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent used Dojo gridx, but looking at one of its basic demos, it is rendering a `<table>` within `<div>` for each row. Using newRow object from your example above, you could do something like following with jquery

```
function() {
    var that = this;
    var gridIdLocal = dijit.byId('GridId');

    that.lastIndex+=1;  ( last index count I get externally)    
    var newRow = {
        Id : '',
        ClassDES:'',
        createdDate: that.getTodayDate(),
        activatedDate:that.getTodayDate(),
        deactivedDate:'',
        activeStatus:'Y',
        id : lastIndex
    };
    gridIdLocal.store.newItem(newRow);
    gridIdLocal.store.save();  

    $(newRow).find("td")[1].children("input").focus();
},
```

If you could post a working jsfiddle, it would be easier to solve.